# why gtk3 iconview calls mapping function 9 times for one row?

Tags: python, gtk3

I have simple iconview widget that read pixbuf from store.  I want to scaled pixbufs so i used iconview`s set_cell_data_func. but there is a problem. it calls it 9 times just for one row and runs more slow even flowbox

```
self.iconmodel = Gtk.ListStore(GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)

self.icon = Gtk.IconView()
self.icon.set_model(self.iconmodel)
self.icon.set_pixbuf_column(0)

self.icon.set_cell_data_func(self.icon.get_cells()[0], self.custom_cell_function, None)

def custom_cell_function(self, cell_layout, cell, tree_model, tree_iter, data):
    p = tree_model[tree_iter][0]
    p = p.scale_simple(p.get_width()*0.33, p.get_height()*0.33, 1)
    cell.set_property('pixbuf', p)
```

In the picture there is 127 pixbuf in the store and calls the func 989 times :) Flowbox seems more suited than icon view but then all thumbs must be widget not cell renderer.
Do you guys have any idea to reduce it? thanks.
[exmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75kpl.png)

Answer (score 0):

i see no pixbufs added to your liststore.
Maybe if you just write:

```
# for p in your_pixbufs
p = p.scale_simple(p.get_width()*0.33, p.get_height()*0.33, 1)
self.iconmodel.append( [p] )
```

instead of the cell_data_func

Comment: i want to change pixbuf size dynamically like in gnome Files`s icon size scale. dont want to put every scaled sizes in store